# Vvlookup on cell change

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, worksheet-function

I am trying to perform a Vlookup in VBA when a cell value changes, looking up a value based on the cell that has changed.

At the moment I have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Frametype")) Is Nothing Then

 On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler:

 Range("Framewidth").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Frame Info").Range("FrameType"), Sheets("Frame Info").Range("FrameTable"), 7, False)

MyErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        Range("Framewidth").Value = "error"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

I've tried assigning the VBA VLOOKUP on it's own to a button and it returns the correct value, but when it's inserted into this worksheet change, it only returns the error.

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Apologies, that is actually included in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `1004` error probably comes from here:

`If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Frametype")) Is Nothing Then`

If the `Range("Frametype")` is not on the worksheet, where the code is. Then the `Target` cannot intersect it, and it throws an error. Depending on what you are trying to do, change the `Intersect()` line to this:

`If Not Intersect(Target, Range([Frametype].Address)) Is Nothing Then`

---

When working with `Worksheet_Change` event, it is a good idea to disable the events, otherwise the code may probably come into a loop.

Another best practice idea is to exit before the `Error Handler`, if you can with `Exit Sub`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range([Frametype].Address)) Is Nothing Then
    'If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Frametype")) Is Nothing Then
        With Worksheets("Frame Info")
            Range("Framewidth").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("FrameType"), _
                                                                .Range("FrameTable"), 7, False)
        End With
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

MyErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then Range("Framewidth").Value = "error"
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've copied this in as the only code, but it's still only returning the error text

Comment: @Richard - can you inspect whether the error is not in `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("FrameType"),.Range("FrameTable"), 7, False)`

Comment: @Richard - Is the code in the "Frame Info" worksheet? I guess that the error comes here - `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Frametype")) Is Nothing Then`, because `Range("Frametype")` is not on the sheet, where the code is.

Comment: The code is on a sheet called "Specification" where the range "Frametype" is

Comment: @Richard - then how is this functioning - `Sheets("Frame Info").Range("FrameType")`?

Comment: That was it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

That was it! Thanks :)
I've changed the code to:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Frametype")) Is Nothing Then

            Sheets("Specification").Range("Framewidth").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Specification").Range("Frametype"), _
                                                                Sheets("Frame Info").Range("FrameTable"), 7, False)

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

MyErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then Range("Framewidth").Value = "error"
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```